# Регулярное выражение для извлечения HTTP-кода ответа

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из строки **"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"** удалять все кроме кода ответа (400)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13232323/860331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно просто вырезать HTTP-код ответа и заменить им исходную строку

```
<?php
  $str = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request";
  preg_match("/\d{3}/", $str, $out);
  $str = $out[0]; // 400
```

Answer (score 1):

Открываем описание протокола HTTP и находим

> Status-Line
>
> The first line of a Response message is the Status-Line, consisting of
>   the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its
>   associated textual phrase, with each element separated by SP
>   characters. No CR or LF is allowed except in the final CRLF sequence.
>
> ```
>    Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
> ```

Всё просто. Числовой код статуса находится во втором поле, поля отделаются друг от дружки пробелом.

```
$statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request";
preg_match("/^(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/", $statusLine, $matches);
$httpVersion  = $matches[1];
$statusCode   = $matches[2];  // здесь ваш код
$reasonPhrase = $matches[3];
```

Посмотреть красивый цветной онлайн тест https://regex101.com/r/sM9uW4/1